# What are the trade-offs of using media="print" vs an @media print declaration in the stylesheet?

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

I'm trying to figure out how to structure my CSS files (which are quite numerous by now), and I'm wondering whether there is any actual difference between having:

```
<link href="blah.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or having:

```
@media print {
   definitions
}
```

I'm asking from the browser's perspective. Are both equally well supported? Can I not care?

Or is one clearly superior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ the use of `@media ...` in CSS files has been supported since HTML4 and CSS2.

> "The ‘print’ and ‘screen’ media types are defined in HTML4. The
>   complete list of media types in HTML4 is: ‘aural’, ‘braille’,
>   ‘handheld’, ‘print’, ‘projection’, ‘screen’, ‘tty’, ‘tv’. CSS2 defines
>   the same list, deprecates ‘aural’ and adds ‘embossed’ and ‘speech’.
>   Also, ‘all’ is used to indicate that the style sheet applies to all
>   media types."

CSS3 expanded the use of `@media ...` to also allow media queries to be used, these are also documented on the w3.org page I linked earlier.

Usage of media types is also documented here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Here is a list of support for media queries:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml

As far as I can tell; use of `@media screen, print, ...` is very widely supported, however the newer media queries that you can use are only supported in CSS3 compatible browsers.

**Edit:** There is even more info about this here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#x2

I wouldn't worry about support for using `@media ...` this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any resource that documents which browsers would support each?

Comment: I've just realised, my answer is wrong! I'm going to correct it now, one moment... Edit: I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use @media print, you won't have to make the additional call for a stylesheet if the user decides to print. The only thing you are giving up is the extra few KB on your stylesheet, but I'd say that's not a bad price to pay for consolidating all your styles.